# How to get count of combinations from database?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get count of combinations from database?

I have to database tables and want to get the count of combinations. Does anybody know how to put this in a database query, therefore I haven't a db request for each trip?

## Trips

```
| ID | Driver | Date       |
|----|--------|------------|
| 1  | A      | 2015-12-15 |
| 2  | A      | 2015-12-16 |
| 3  | B      | 2015-12-17 |
| 4  | A      | 2015-12-18 |
| 5  | A      | 2015-12-19 |
```

## Passengers

```
| ID | PassengerID | TripID |
|----|-------------|--------|
| 1  | B           | 1      |
| 2  | C           | 1      |
| 3  | D           | 1      |
| 4  | B           | 2      |
| 5  | D           | 2      |
| 6  | A           | 3      |
| 7  | B           | 4      |
| 8  | D           | 4      |
| 9  | B           | 5      |
| 10 | C           | 5      |
```

## Expected result

```
| Driver | B-C-D | B-D | A | B-C |
|--------|-------|-----|---|-----|
| A      | 1     | 2   | - | 1   |
| B      | -     | -   | 1 | -   |
```

### Alternative

```
| Driver | Passengers | Count |
|--------|------------|-------|
| A      | B-C-D      | 1     |
| A      | B-D        | 2     |
| A      | B-C        | 1     |
| B      | A          | 1     |
```

Has anybody an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the expected result if there's also another trip with only B and C as passengers and A as driver?

Comment: Example added to the post

Comment: So you are asking for a query that returns a dynamic number of columns, depending on the current table data?

Comment: Also possible will be a structure where the columns are in the secons columns of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Driver, Passengers, COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM (
  SELECT t.ID, t.Driver, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(p.PassengerID 
                      ORDER BY p.PassengerID 
                      SEPARATOR '-') AS Passengers
  FROM Trips AS t
  INNER JOIN Passengers AS p ON t.ID = p.TripID
  GROUP BY t.ID, t.Driver) AS t
GROUP BY Driver, Passengers
```

The above query will produce the alternative result set. The other result set can only be achieved using dynamic sql.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06a69/5)